# Intellij: Avoiding 'Multiple Dex Files Defined'

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

**Problem:**

Up until now I've been using Gradle to handle all of my dependencies, and it seems to take care of any duplicate dependencies between other Gradle modules. However, this does not seem to be the case when a duplicate dependency exists within a jar.

**Question:**

Considering that I have control over what goes into the jar, What is the best practices for handling these dependency conflicts using Gradle:

1. Do not include any external dependencies in the jar, include them in the project itself using `build.gradle`
2. Include all external dependcies in the jar, remove duplicates as they occur by removing them from the project `build.gradle`. (**NOTE:** this does not seem scalable, e.g. if there are duplicates between jars themselves.)
3. Something better (that hopefully handles this automatically)

**EDIT:** `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release { ... }
        debug { ... }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig { ... }
    buildTypes {
        release { ... }
        debug { ... }
    } 
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile project(':jarModule')
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jars? Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Basically, I have a Java project in Intellij that I build into a jar, and then import the jar as a module in Android Studio. The module is included in the build.gradle using `compile project(':jarModule')`

Comment: Post your all of your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows okay posted it.

Comment: We all need to see your "jarModule" `build.gradle`. How else can we help determine what is conflicting?

Comment: @JaredBurrows, Oh I know what is conflicting. In this case it's that I had Gson defined in the apps build.gradle and included in the jar. I have fixed the problem by removing Gson from my build.gradle, but my question is what is the best way to handle this.

Comment: Then what is the problem? I have the same dependencies in android library projects and android apps. Make sure they are the same version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75066/discussion-between-bcorso-and-jared-burrows).

Comment: I think that in your case, you can just exclude dependencies, which you have already defined for the main project from the "jarModule". You can easily do it in `build.gradle` file with braces and `exclude` keyword for appropriate dependency. E.g. `compile project(':jarModule') { exclude ... }` and replace dots with duplicated dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing external `jars` that have a dependency that you also have in your local app, you can do two things:

### Convert your `jar` dependency to a Gradle dependency and exclude the dependency

For example:

```
testCompile('org.robospock:robospock:0.5.0')  {
     exclude module: "groovy-all" // <-- excludes groovy from robo spock
}
```

or

### Remove the local dependency in your app and rely on the one in the `.jar`

For example, in your case with `Gson`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile project(':jarModule')
    // compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1' // <-- removed
}
```